# Failing to Install Bouncycastle provider

Tags: java, bouncycastle, java-9, jce

I am running on Java 9 and tried to execute a program with following line.

```
Security.getProvider("BC");
```

However, this returns null. As a solution I tried following line.

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

But it gives me an error saying,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider
```

I have added "bcprov-jdk15on-156" jar file to my idea project with scope:provided. Furthermore I have set  crypto.policy to unlimited.

I tried to add provider statically also by adding "`security.provider.14=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider`" to java.security file in both jdk-9.0.4/conf/security folder and  jdk-9.0.4/conf/security folder. But i am still receiving same error with no provider installing.

What am I missing here?

Comment: if `Object p = new BouncyCastleProvider()` fails with NoClassDefFoundDefError when it suggests that this class is not on the class path.

Comment: I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, I have added bc jar in idea, please find image here where I have added jars https://pasteboard.co/H9Jdcp2.png Am I doing it correctly.

Comment: Does it work outside of the IDE?

Comment: Do you also see a `caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`? Or just the `NoClassDefFoundError`?